# Qt Login Timeout Using QTimer

Tags: c++, qt, authentication, timer, qtimer

I am trying to implement a login timeout when the username/password has been entered wrong too many time. But i am unable to do so. My code is below

```
ui->label->setText("Password entered wrong too many times, entered 10 minute cooldown period");
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update())); 
    timer->start(6000);
    ui->pushButton->setVisible(false);
    if(!timer->isActive())
        ui->pushButton->setVisible(true);
```

Comment: So, it simply doesn't wait?

Comment: what it does is it makes the button invisible but it does not make the button visible again

Comment: And in what method of what class is this code located?

Comment: this is in the clicked slot of the "Login" Pushbutton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ui->pushButton->hide();
QTimer::singleShot(5000, ui->pushButton, SLOT(show()));
```